# Secure Stripe Payment

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl-certificate, stripe-payments

I'm running a Stripe test payment on an ASP Net site. When the user is ready to pay they are FORWARDED to their gateway to collect card details.

Once they complete a successful payment they are returned to the success URL i set with the {SESSION_ID} variable alongside the URL i.e. www.example.com/success?session_id{Session_ID}.

I then process the payment by getting the session first

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_123";

var service = new SessionService();
Checkout.Session sess service.Get("cs_test_4561");
```

I then find the payment from my database using the session id i saved and passed when the user checked out.

My concern is that through a web sniffer tool the Session ID can be picked up and you can pass that manually to the successURL.

I can add HTTPS to the site but is there anything else i could do to make this a little more difficult i.e. expire the Session ID after some time or have a value from Strip to confirm the payment is successful?

Edit 1:

My code behind to set the SessionCreateOptions

```
 var options = new SessionCreateOptions
            {
                PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> { "card", },
                LineItems = GetItems(),
                SuccessUrl = "www.example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
                CancelUrl = "www.example.com/cancel",

                PaymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
                {
                    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>{
                        {"orderID","123"}
                    }
                },
                Mode="payment",
            };
 var service = new SessionService();
 Session session = service.Create(options);
```

When the user is returned back to the success page, i run this code to get the session i run the above code to get the Session but payment_intent is null if i type sess.PaymentIntent

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve the CheckoutSession by its `id`, you should check its `payment_intent` to verify that it shows `status: succeeded`. That shows that the payment went through without issue.

More details on the entire process here:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment

Comment: Thanks payment_intent is always null and i'm not sure why? When i run service.Get(cs_test_4561) i store this in an object and it contains payment_intent but as null, pay,ent_intentId is there but not a succeed value? What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: If the payment_intent is null, that would indicate that the payment hasn't gone through yet (the CheckoutSession isn't actually successful).

Comment: I've add my SessionCreateOptions to my original post and Session showing the way i retrieve it. If it wasnt successful then why is it sending back to my success_Url? thx

Comment: You'll want to make sure you're retrieving the most current version of the CheckoutSession from the API. If you're still running into issues there, I'd suggest contacting the Stripe team via https://support.stripe.com/contact as they'll be able to look at your CheckoutSession directly and see what's up.